# Parse 30 req per second meaning.

Tags: parse-platform

My app is a chat app that sends push notification(message) to members in their address book. So if I have 100 people in my address book - I can send "Hi" to all of those people and they will receive that "Hi" message.

What does Parse request per second mean? This is stupid but will only 30 people receive that message? and the message will not go through for 70 other people?

What does 30/per second mean?

Thank You!

Comment: It means that if you have 100 messages to send, it will take 100/30 = a bit more than 3 seconds to process all.

Comment: The way said limit is implemented may vary from service to service. Some may spread the requests out over several seconds to abide by the req/s rule (otherwise known as *burst*), others may just ignore anything over the limit and instead return in error. based on the faq, i would expect parse.com to ignore things that are over the limit and return error. https://parse.com/plans/faq/ Note that sending the same message to 100 people can probably be done in 1 request, see @Logan's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Requests pertains to number of times your App sends a request to the server.  If you manage it right, with your channels you could probably send all the push notifications in 1 request.  All 100 people will receive the push as long as you haven't exceeded your push limit. (Unlimited pushes to up to 1 million unique recipients).

Now if the push triggers a call to Parse to download more information about the message, and all 100 happen to get the push at the same time, only 30 per second will be allowed.  The rest will take a bit longer or time out.

Comment: Hi @Logan, will you please explain "If you manage it right, with your channels you could probably send all the push notifications in 1 request".  Thanks for your help